Time changes in reported speech
Context it's Monday
I will do it today
Now it's Friday
I want to report this setnce
He said he would do it that day
Ok. That's fine but "that day" it's not specific we don't know when excatly something was said. How to inform someone that is happened on Monday
He said he would do it 5 days before
But it would mean that he said " I will do it 5 days ago" doesn't make sense.
Then, how to express it using other way than just saying
He said he would do it on Monday. Is there any other way?

One way is to modify the entire sentence with a time indicator first - "On Monday / Five days ago, he said he would do it that day" (with the latter, I'd personally prefer the same day).

Thank so much. Any other solutions?

There are grammatical rules that govern verb tense in reported speech, but there is no grammatical rule specific to reported speech that says how time references must be handled. There you simply have to convey information clearly and with the specificity required by your situation. You could say "He said on Monday that he'd do it {that day, immediately, right away, etc}"   If all you need to convey is that it should be done already, you are free to express it as you like; but if the situation demands a very precise formulation, you might have to say something like "by the next business day".

You could say "On Monday he said he would have it be done by the end of the day".  We would normally add "today" if he was referring to a future day: "On Monday he said he would have it be done by the end of the day today."  and that would be the day the speech was being reported. So a native speaker would understand the first one to mean "by the end of the day on Monday, the day he said it"

"I will do it today" he said on Monday

@jsotola He said today he will do it on Monday.

Simplest way to say it:
"He said he would do it on Monday."
Another variation:
"He said on Monday that he would do it that day."

The second variation is a good reporting of the OP. The first variation is ambiguous; I read it as a future commitment. The promise is made before Monday, and he will get it done when next Monday arrives.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
